# How to merge two xml.Elem vals?

Tags: xml, scala, merge, functional-programming

I have two xml.Elem vals and i need to insert one as a child to a node of the other one. In detail that means:

```
val a = <p id="s" name="S">
    <sE id="st" name="St"></sE>
    <sProcess id="s_process" name="SP"></sProcess>
  </p>

val b = <p id="e" name="S">
    <sE id="dd" name="DD"></sE>
    </p>
```

and i need to insert all the Childs from the Node labeled p of Elem b as childs to the Node labeled sProcess in the a Elem. So that after this has been applied it looks like this:

```
val a = <p id="s" name="S">
<sE id="st" name="St"></sE>
<sProcess id="s_process" name="SP">
 <sE id="dd" name="DD"></sE></sProcess>
</p>
```

My approach till now was this:

```
a.foreach(n => ...)
```

But this only visits the Node labeled p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use the `b.child()` method, it will give you a `Seq[Node]` of all the Childs from the Node labled p. You can then change the definition of  `val a` to a function by using function as a type.

```
val a : Seq[Node] => Elem = (x:Seq[Node]) => <p id="s" name="S">
    <sE id="st" name="St"> {x} </sE>
    <sProcess id="s_process" name="SP"></sProcess>
  </p>
```